# How to over ride the transparency aspect in CSS

Tags: html, css

It is my understanding that when one places the transparency aspect on an element, the opacity always remains on top. My question is: What is the best way to place an element on top of the opacity.

Here is the Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6xV4B/

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
   <ul id="social" class="center">
       <li><a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook Icon" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter Icon" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="images/linkedIn.png" alt="linkedIn Icon" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="backgroundOne">
    <div id="backgroundTwo" class="center"></div>
</div>

<div id="blankTile1"></div>

<div id="myPicture" class="center">
    <div id="logo"></div>
</div>

<div id="blanktileTwo"></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #643b0f;
    opacity: .5;
}
#social {
    width: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#social li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
}
#social li a {
    padding: 0 50px;
}
#backgroundOne {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
    background-color: blue;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
#myPicture {
    width: 650px;
    height: 955px;
    margin: -1200px 0 0 325px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#backgroundTwo {
    width: 960px;
    height: 1200px;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: .5;
}
#logo {
    background-color: green;
}
#blankTile1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 478px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
#blankTile2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 478px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

(For further understanding - this is the beginning of a parallax project. This is in order to learn this technique.)

Comment: What do you mean with "the opacity always remains on top"? If you only your background to be transparent, use RGBA.

Comment: I would like to have multiple layers with opacity, perhaps a pic is the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

So, one `solution` is to use a tiny transparent `PNG` as a repeating background image to work around that. The only issue there is IE6, and there's this [Links](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6/)